# Read Json array vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm getting mad about this.
I'm very new to Json.
I need to read the array ("items") from the json example provided.
I can read all other objets like "id","title","description"...but not the array of items.
Using Newtonsoft.Jason

Code (vb.net) : >>

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Test\Json\test.json")
    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
    Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

    For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
        Select item.Name
            Case "results"
                For Each comment As JObject In item.Values
                    txtConsole.Text = comment
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("id"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("title"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("description"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("tipe"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("author")("description"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("details")("conditions"))

                    'for each item in array
                        'Read the array of "products": here
                        'Console.WriteLine(comment("name")
                        'Console.WriteLine(comment("codeBar")
                    'next

                    Console.WriteLine(comment("details")("benefits"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("details")("price"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("details")("discount"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("details")("pays"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("datefrom"))
                    Console.WriteLine(comment("dateto"))
                Next

        End Select
    Next
```

Json file >>

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 208,
      "title": "This is the title",
      "description": "This is the descripcion",
      "tipe": "This is type",
      "author": {
        "descripcion": "description of author"
      },
      "details": {
        "conditions": {
          "items": [
            {
              "quantity": 6,
              "products": [
                {
                  "name": "Product one",
                  "codeBar": "7891000100103"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Product two",
                  "codeBar": "7894900061604"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Product three",
                  "codeBar": "7894900010015"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Product four",
                  "codeBar": "7894900092011"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "benefits": null,
        "price": null,
        "discount": null,
        "pays": 5
      },
      "datefrom": "2015-08-06T00:00:00.000-0300",
      "dateto": "2016-12-31T23:59:59.000-0200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desire Console output >>

```
208
This is the title
This is the descripcion
This is type

items
quantity: 6
products
          "name": "Product one",
          "codeBar": "7891000100103"

          "name": "Product two",
          "codeBar": "7894900061604"

          "name": "Product three",
          "codeBar": "7894900010015"

          "name": "Product four",
          "codeBar": "7894900092011"

5
06/08/2015 00:00:00
31/12/2016 22:59:59
```

Please, help me...thank u very much in advance !!

Comment: Have you considered deserializing it ?

Comment: till then, `For Each element In comment("details")("conditions")("items")(0)("products")`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might point you in the right direction. I was able to access the products array this way:

```
        ' Open the file using a stream reader.
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\json.txt")
    Dim line As String

    line = sr.ReadToEnd()
    line = "[" & line & "]"

    Dim jArray__1 = JArray.Parse(line)

    For Each item In jArray__1.SelectToken("[0].results.[0].details.conditions.items.[0].products")
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thak you very much guys !!
I finally did it like this...

```
For Each element In comment.SelectToken("details")("conditions")("items")(0)("products")
    Console.WriteLine(element("name"))
    Console.WriteLine(element("codeBar"))
Next
```